# Pascal's triangle program failed

Tags: python, python-3.x

code:

```
def pascaltri(r):
  for i2 in range(1,r+1):
    string = ""
    string += " "*int(r-i2)
    string += " ".join(map(str, str(11**i2-1)))
    print(string)
  pascaltri(5)
```

This gives me:

```
    1 0
   1 2 0
  1 3 3 0
 1 4 6 4 0
1 6 1 0 5 0
```

What I want is this:

```
       1
      1 1
     1 2 1
    1 3 3 1
   1 4 6 4 1
```

Please tell me why and how I can fix the zero's and put a one on top?
Help appreciated.

Comment: This should be helpful for you: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close using that powers of 11 "trick". Just note that **it only works up to 5**.

To get this "working", you really only needed to fix some "off by one" errors:

```
def pascaltri(r):
    for i2 in range(r):
        string = " " * (r - i2)
        string += " ".join(map(str, str(11 ** i2)))
        print(string)

pascaltri(5)
```

This should now give you:

```
     1
    1 1
   1 2 1
  1 3 3 1
 1 4 6 4 1
```

**Remember this trick falls apart after 5 so you will likely want a better (general) solution.**

---

This is not a "general solution to Pascal's Triangle" but rather one that specifically addresses the original poster's question of

> "How to print the initial 1 and how to fix the trailing zeros?"

My answer addresses these questions and I clearly noted twice that the method proposed by the original poster falls apart after 5.

Here is a real solution for pascal's triangle:

```
def printPascal(n):
    for row in range(1, n + 1):
        cell_value = 1
        print(cell_value, end=" ")
        for cell in range(1, row):
            cell_value = int(cell_value * (row - cell) / cell)
            print(cell_value, end=" ")
        print("")
```

Now you can get to printPascal(10). I'll leave it to you to determine how you want to do spacing.